# How to remove the login swipe screen using Registry edits in Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, login-screen, gpedit

I want to eliminate the need to swipe the screen before getting to the log in screen on my Win 8.1 Update computer. I do not have the pro version so there is no gpedit.msc utility present.

What registry keys should I modify to remove this nuisance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**This works in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10**

You can use the registry editor do disable the lock screen image, which will remove the need to swipe the lock screen every time you want to unlock your computer (so when you press WinKey + L, it only shows your logon image and password field):

1. In the registry editor, navigate to the following key (if the key does not exist, you will have to create it manually):  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`
2. Select **Personalization** key and in right-side pane, create a new DWORD **NoLockScreen** and set its value to **1**.
3. Close Registry Editor and log off or restart Windows to take effect. It'll completely turn off lock screen.

If you want to restore lock screen in future, just delete the DWORD or set its value to **0**.

*[Source](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-lock-screen-in-windows-8/)*

Comment: I don't have a Personalization key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\

Comment: Did you read the part in parentheses? `if the key does not exist, you will have to create it manually`, which you can do by right-clicking the `Windows` key and selecting "New" --> "Key"

Comment: Yes, I saw it but had to look twice. And then before I could stop writing that question I pushed enter and my comment flew away. 

I added the key and the value. The lock screen is gone. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: You're welcome! To help others easily find the correct answer, feel free to mark it as "accepted" :D

Comment: **CurrentVersion** is missing in the initial answer. It is actually `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Personalization`

Comment: This also works for Windows 10 so someone should add that as a tag